# How to run decorator at each request before wrapper?

Tags: python, fastapi

I'd like to run some code before a view even build dependencies (please note the comment marked with `===>`):

```
from functools import wraps

import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends

app = FastAPI()


def get_session():
    print("get session")


def transaction():
    print("inside transaction")
    def decorator(func):
        print("inside decorator")
        # ===> I need to run code here at each request
        @wraps(func)
        async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print("inside wrapper")
            result = await func(*args, **kwargs)
            return result
        return wrapper
    return decorator


@app.post("/create")
@transaction()
async def create(session=Depends(get_session)):
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app, port=8000)
```

The output when ran:

```
inside transaction
inside decorator
INFO:     Started server process [67644]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     127.0.0.1:60098 - "GET /docs HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
INFO:     127.0.0.1:60098 - "GET /openapi.json HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
get session
inside wrapper
```

The problem with it is that I'd like the code `print("inside decorator")` should be ran at each http request. In other words I need to run some code before `wrapper` at each request (I need to initialize something). How could I do this?

Comment: Then `print('inside decorator')` should actually be inside `wrapper`.

Comment: `transaction` gets called exactly once to produce the function `decorator` which is *also* called exactly once to bind the name `create` to the new function `wrapper` which wraps the function originally bound to `create`.

Comment: Each time you call `create`, you execute `wrapper`, not the decorator that defines `wrapper`.

Comment: Yes, I understand it.